# ExUnit: Data Directories

Tags: unit-testing, erlang, elixir

In Erlang's [common_test](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ct.html), a test suite `a_SUITE.erl` is associated with a corresponding [data directory](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/common_test/write_test_chapter.html#data_priv_dir)  `a_SUITE_data/`, which is used to store files used by the test suite. That directory can then be found in `a_SUITE` using the `?config/2` macro: `?config(data_dir, Config)`.

Is there an equivalent for `ExUnit`, or do Elixir projects usually have a convention on how to achieve this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't any equivalent. I personally just create a directory in `test/` and use that, usually `test/data` or `test/fixtures`.